# VS Code Conditional Snippets

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-snippets, vscode-extensions

I am looking to have some snippets listed conditionally in the VS Code IntelliSense for a particular language. I am considering creating an extension, intercepting the list of `CompletionItems`, and removing any snippets that do not satisfy my conditions based on languageId and settings/configuration I will contribute with the extension. I am looking for the simplest solution to accomplish this, but if I need a Language Server then so be it. If I can dynamically load a snippets file for a particular languageId then that would be even better. I just need a starting point from someone more familiar with the API. I haven't even found how to retrieve `CompletionList` to start the intercept -- I searched the API doc but found nothing but its object definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of VSCode 1.14, you cannot have conditional [user snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) but an extension can contribute snippets conditionally. Try looking into creating a `CompletionItemProvider` that returns completion items with their `kind` set to `CompletionItemKind.Snippet`.

The [`JsDocCompletionProvider`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/typescript/src/features/jsDocCompletionProvider.ts#L52) in the VSCode codebase is one example of this pattern. It only returns jsdoc snippets when the area around the cursor matches a regular expression

Comment: Updated `jsDocCompletionProvider` link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/94c9ea46838a9a619aeafb7e8afd1170c967bb55/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/languageFeatures/jsDocCompletions.ts